# How to use Auth0 JWT with angularjs for payLoad data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jwt, auth0

I am new to auth0 Here, I am getting an JWT-Token in the login request .

So, Lets say, "12344566" thie is the JWT-Token. now , I have now stored this in the localstorage .

```
jwtOptionsProvider.config({
            tokenGetter: function() {
              return localStorage.getItem("AuthToken");
            },
        });

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('jwtInterceptor');
```

I am using jwtInterceptor for sendig this token in every request . Now,

below is my request ->

```
addToOntology: function (ontologyName, currentNode, orphan, type) {
                    var config = {};
                    config.headers = {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",

                    };
                    var jsonData = {
                        "ontologyName": ontologyName,
                        "orphanName": orphan,
                        "orphanType": type
                    };
                    return $http.put('abv/ontology/' + currentNode.name, jsonData, config)
                        .then(function (success) {
                            return success;
                        },
                        function (error) {
                            $log.error(error);
                            return $q.reject(error);
                        });
                },
```

Now, If you see here this is my service which is calling a rest api . Here I am sending jsonData . Right now with this code Authorization Bearer 123456 This gets added in header but the jsonData is not getting converted in the jwt . So, How can I do this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "but the jsonData is not getting converted in the jwt" mean?

Comment: I mean the  var jsonData = {
                        "ontologyName": ontologyName,
                        "orphanName": orphan,
                        "orphanType": type
                    };  This data is going to be a part of the request.And this data is the payload and is sent as a request payload.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear to me. You wrote "... in the jwt". What does the JWT have to do with the request payload? The token is in the Authorization header, the JSON data in the request body.. Pls. click on edit to add more information to your question.